# remove double quotes around dictionary object - python

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a dictionary that I am using to populate a YAML config file for each key.

```
{'id': ['HP:000111'], 'id1': ['HP:000111'], 'id2': ['HP:0001111', 'HP:0001123'])}
```

code to insert key:value pair into YAML template using `ruamel.yaml`

```
import ruamel.yaml
import sys

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
with open('yaml.yml') as fp:
    data = yaml.load(fp)

for k in start.keys():
    data['analysis']['hpoIds'] = start.get(key)
       with open(f"path/yaml-{k}.yml","w+") as f:
           yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

this is output I am getting

```
analysis:
    # hg19 or hg38 - ensure that the application has been configured to run the specified assembly otherwise it will halt.
  genomeAssembly: hg38
  vcf:
  ped:
  proband:
  hpoIds: "['HP:000111','HP:000112','HP:000113']"
```

but this is what I need

```
  hpoIds: ['HP:000111','HP:000112','HP:000113']
```

ive tried using string tools i.e strip, replace but didnt

output from `ast.literal_eval.`

```
hpoIds:
  - HP:000111
  - HP:000112
  - HP:000113
```

output from `repr`

```
hpoIds: "\"['HP:000111','HP: 000112','HP:000113']\""
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Seems like the `ast.literal_eval` is already doing what you want (though you're printing it funny; presumably with YAML output format). Seems like changing `data['analysis']['hpoIds'] = start.get(key)` to `data['analysis']['hpoIds'] = ast.literal_eval(start.get(key))` would do exactly what you want. Why is that not sufficient?

Comment: this works. I wrongly assumed the formatting `ast.literal_eval(start.get(key))` wouldn't be compatible but tested it out and works just fine. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do and why you e.g. open files
'w+' for dumping.

However if you have something that comes out block style and unquoted, that  can easily be remedied
by using a small function:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

SQ = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.SingleQuotedScalarString

def flow_seq_single_quoted(lst):
    res = ruamel.yaml.CommentedSeq([SQ(x) if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in lst])
    res.fa.set_flow_style()
    return res

in_file = Path('yaml.yaml') 
in_file.write_text("""\
hpoIds:
  - HP:000111
  - HP:000112
  - HP:000113
""")

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(in_file)
data['hpoIds'] = flow_seq_single_quoted(data['hpoIds'])

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
hpoIds: ['HP:000111', 'HP:000112', 'HP:000113']
```

The recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006.

Comment: thank you so much. @shadowranger comment actually solved it...errr..helped me realize there wasnt a problem in the first place! This bit of code works as well. very much appreciate the time/effort